# R graphics: How to make objects from VennDiagram compatible with cowplot plot_grid?

Tags: r, r-grid, venn-diagram, cowplot, grob

I am making Venn diagrams with the VennDiagram package. They are coming out OK:

```
library(VennDiagram)
library(cowplot)


png("p.png")
p = draw.pairwise.venn(30,20,11, category = c("Dogs", "Cats"), lty = rep("blank", 2), fill = c("light blue", "pink"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(-45, 45), cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))
dev.off()

png("q.png")
draw.pairwise.venn(15, 20, 10, category = c("Rats", "Mice"), lty = rep("blank", 2), fill = c("light blue", "pink"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(-45, 45), cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))
dev.off()
```

[image]
[image]

But if I try to plot them side by side using cowplot's plot_grid() bad things occur:

```
p = draw.pairwise.venn(30,20,11, category = c("Dogs", "Cats"), lty = rep("blank", 2), fill = c("light blue", "pink"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(-45, 45), cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))

q = draw.pairwise.venn(15, 20, 10, category = c("Rats", "Mice"), lty = rep("blank", 2), fill = c("light blue", "pink"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(-45, 45), cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))

png('pq.png')
plot_grid(p, q, labels = "AUTO")
dev.off()

Error: Argument needs to be of class "ggplot", "gtable", "grob", "recordedplot", or a function that plots to an R graphicsdevice when called, but is a gList
Calls: plot_grid -> align_plots -> lapply -> FUN -> plot_to_gtable
Execution halted
```

`draw.pairwise.venn()` is not making objects compatible with `plot_grid()`.

```
class(p)
[1] "gList"
```

So I guess I need to make gList into ggplot object or something else compatible, even though `gList` is listed as a suitable type. I have not been able to find anything. I want to use cowplot due to its nice ability to label sub figures for publication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping these plots into a `grobTree()` works for me. I think the VennDiagram package is to blame here. It shouldn't return a `gList`, it should wrap the `gList` into a grob. In any case, this can be fixed in cowplot. Feel free to file an issue [here.](https://github.com/wilkelab/cowplot/issues)

```r
library(VennDiagram)
#> Loading required package: grid
#> Loading required package: futile.logger
library(cowplot)
library(grid)

p = draw.pairwise.venn(30,20,11, category = c("Dogs", "Cats"), lty = rep("blank", 2), fill = c("light blue", "pink"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(-45, 45), cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))

q = draw.pairwise.venn(15, 20, 10, category = c("Rats", "Mice"), lty = rep("blank", 2), fill = c("light blue", "pink"), alpha = rep(0.5, 2), cat.pos = c(-45, 45), cat.dist = rep(0.025, 2))

plot_grid(grobTree(p), grobTree(q), labels = "AUTO")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).